# How do I add comments on an algorithm environment in LaTeX?

Tags: algorithm, latex

I am using LaTeX to write a pseudo algorithm using the `algorithm` package. I want to add comments on the code in a way that they get aligned. The following lines are what I could do, but the comments are not aligned. How do I do that?

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{}
\label{}
    \begin{tabbing}
     quad \=\quad \=\quad \kill
     \keyw{for} each a $\in$ A \keyw{do} \\
     \> command; \qquad \qquad $\blacktriangleright$ add text here \\
     \keyw{end} \\

\end{tabbing}
\end{algorithm}

The comments are like that:
 one comment here\\
               other here\\
     other here\\
```

How do I align them?

Comment: Please post this question at [tex.se].

Comment: @NicoSchertler: It doesn't help voting to close (with a migration suggestion) and then suggesting to post it to the target site as well. Either vote-to-close with migration or vote-to-close as off-topic and suggest re-posting.

Comment: A same question with  [How do you add a comment to pseudocode in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35621/how-do-you-add-a-comment-to-pseudocode-in-latex)

Answer (score 8):

If you're setting algorithms, use a dedicated pseudo code setting package. Here's one using [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)'s `algpseudocode`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\algnewcommand{\algorithmicforeach}{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{SE}[FOR]{ForEach}{EndForEach}[1]
  {\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}% \ForEach{#1}
  {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicforeach}% \EndForEach

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \ForEach{$a \in A$}%
      \State command \algorithmiccomment{This is a comment}
      \State another command \algorithmiccomment{This is another comment}
    \EndForEach
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

`algpseudocode` already defines `\ForAll`. However, in the above code, I copied that definition into `\ForEach`. Comments can be added using `\algorithmiccomment`. Formatting and placement can be modified.

Comment: How can I change its format `|>` into `//`

Comment: @alper: Add `\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill// #1}` to your preamble after loading [`algpseudocode`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx).

Comment: Can I put `\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\textbf{//}\,#1}` instead?

Comment: @alper: Yeah, why not!